What is the difference between creating a "Java Class" file and "Kotlin Class/File"?
I'm used to making Android apps in Java but I wanted to try making an app in Kotlin. I created the Kotlin project, and I have a nice, Kotlin-app by now. However, when I wanted to create a new fragment, I realized that I have been using both Java Class files and Kotlin Class/File files in my project all this time. I was not aware of it. Yet, the project works properly and there are no Kotlin errors.
Is there a noticeable difference between using only Kotlin Class/File files in your Kotlin project VS using Java Class files in your Kotlin project?


I don't see any difference. The code snippet suggestions are the same, there are no warnings or errors, the syntax highlighting works properly. Someone please explain.

see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html

You can use both Java & Kotlin classes in one project if you need, as Java and Kotlin both can call each other code smoothly.

It is perfectly normal to mix code between Java and Kotlin.

I don’t see any Java class files above. All those icons have a little purple K for Kotlin.
The ones with the C in the icon mean the file has a single class defined in it instead of multiple classes or containing top level functions or properties.
A Java class would not compile if it had Kotlin code in it. The file extension is .java instead of .kt.

Ahh that makes sense. I was confused by the "C" icon also appearing before the "Java Class" option.
